# Angular calendar external event drop to day view scheduler

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

I am working on the Angular calendar and the requirement is to drop external event to the day timeline to specific user.

I am using day-view-scheduler for day view timeline and external events.
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/day-view-scheduler

Problem is when dropping external event to the specific user it will automatically move to the default user which was added in externalEvents, if there was any workaround please let me know.

[Demo Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZctk.gif)

Comment: Share examples, please. What do you expect and/or what are you get

Comment: I have updated question and added gif please check that, when i am drop event in user 2 it will automatically move to user 1, but our requirement is to drop event to specific user.